# Did open layers replace the splitWith functionality or just remove it in v3?

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I can't find any documentation on what happened to splitWith.  It used to belong to ol.geom but was only implemented for linestrings.

Does anyone know whether it was removed or replaced and why?

Comment: You can use [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org) with OpenLayers for spatial operations like [splitting a line](http://turfjs.org/docs#lineSplit). There is an [example for using Turf&OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/turf.html) on the OL examples page.